# Failure while calling nsIX509CertDB.nsIX509CertDB from command line

Tags: javascript, certificate, xpcom, x509, nss

I'm trying to develop a FF extension that calls nsIX509CertDB.nsIX509CertDB. When calling this function from a xpcshell I alwas receive a error 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE). I suspect it to be failing since in a xpcshell environment I can not be prompted for the password. Is there any way to provide it from the command line?

My code:

```
if(nsIFile != null && nsIFile.exists()) {
        var certDB = Cc["@mozilla.org/security/x509certdb;1"]
                                        .getService(Ci.nsIX509CertDB);
        certDB.importPKCS12File(null, nsIFile);
}
```

Comment: I guess that the equivalent NSS command line tools won't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would most likely involve writing code to replace `@mozilla.org/nsCertificateDialogs;1` component (implementing [`nsICertificateDialogs` interface](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/bfc259be3fa2/security/manager/ssl/public/nsICertificateDialogs.idl)). Then you could implement `getPKCS12FilePassword` method any way you like.

The simpler approach would be using [`pk12util` tool](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/pk12util.html) included in NSS. Unless this *really* needs to be done via xpcshell of course.

Comment: It's a unit test of a firefox plugin. So i really would like to have it in there.... Thanks for your answer so far! I try to override the nsICertificateDialogs. Could you give me any hints on how to register my implementation?

Comment: You would use [nsIComponentRegistrar.registerFactory()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIComponentRegistrar) (use `Components.manager.nsIComponentRegistrar` to get the service). You will need to unregister the old factory first (use `nsIComponentRegistrar.unregisterFactory`) - for that you will need the CID of the existing implementation (use `nsIComponentRegistrar.contractIDToCID`) and its factory (use [`Components.manager.getClassObject(..., Components.interfaces.nsIFactory)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIComponentManager#getClassObjectByContractID%28%29).

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988107/replace-nsicertificatedialogs-from-firefox-extension